# VirtualDocumentRoot handling non-existent folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost, httpd.conf, vhosts

Using Apache, I have set up the VirtualDocumentRoot and it works this way:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerName app.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/home/domains/example.com/%1"
    <Directory "/home/domains/example.com/*">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If I put the URL of `http://mail.example.com`, the DocRoot becomes `/home/domains/example.com/mail`, if it is `http://www.example.com`, the DocRoot becomes `/home/domains/example.com/www`, and so on.

Now I would like to check for the folder if it exists, like when the user requests a domain like `http://myusername.example.com`, the DocRoot checks `/home/domains/example.com/myusername` and it doesn't exist, so it should refer to `/home/domains/example.com/404`. Is this possible?

I have referred the following questions but no good:

- [VirtualDocumentRoot Domains and Subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478511/virtualdocumentroot-domains-and-subdomains)
- [Apache VirtualDocumentRoot redirect non-existing domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971407/apache-virtualdocumentroot-redirect-non-existing-domains)

Comment: This seems to be an interesting and new problem +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have virtual subdomains that are mapped to folders then couldn't you just check for the existance of the document root? If not exists redirect to the `404 subdomain` which in turn should use `/home/domains/example.com/404` perhaps like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerName app.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/home/domains/example.com/%1"
    <Directory "/home/domains/example.com/*">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*) http://404.example.com/ [R=301,L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Or if the full virtualdocumentroot path is not being picked up by `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` variable because of the dynamic assignment, maybe try it this way by assiging subdomain to a env variable then use it to check the path.

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
        UseCanonicalName Off
        ServerName app.example.com
        ServerAlias *.example.com
        VirtualDocumentRoot "/home/domains/example.com/%1"
        <Directory "/home/domains/example.com/*">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order Allow,Deny
            Allow from all
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com [NC]
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=virt_path:%1,N,NS]

            RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{ENV:virt_path} !-d
            RewriteRule ^(.*) http://404.example.com/ [R=301,L]
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Wow... This looks promising. Let me try this! :)

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem indeed. You need to handle it by placing a custom `404` handler in `<VirtualHost>` section.

Add this line just below `<VirtualHost *:80>`:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/404.html
```

This will try to open `/home/domains/example.com/www/404.html` when you visit:

```
http://myusername.example.com
```

And corresponding folder doesn't exist in your filesystem.

Comment: This logically looks right, but I am not sure. Will try and let you know.

Comment: No issue, take your time and leave a comment here if there is any doubt or question.