# Is it possible with .htaccess to show a 404 page with sub-domains?

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

Is it possible to make with .htaccess a 404 with a sub-domain.

I am making a host that you can get a sub-domain like:

```
example.example.com
```

But, I would like to show a 404 page if a sub-domain does not exist.

```
doesnotexist.example.com
```

Is this possible with .htaccess?

Thanks!

Comment: How do your subdomains work? are they subfolders in the root directory of the main domain or do they have their own structure?

Comment: subfolders in the root directory of the main domain

Comment: Here's a solution albeit a bit tricky should solve your issue using `virtualdocument root.` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627286/virtualdocumentroot-handling-non-existent-folders